# SELECT latest entry of versioned SQL text field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a log table where one of the fields is a `filename`. These filenames are versioned with a suffix at the end of filename. Say we made file `SampleName.xml` but later had to revise this -- the new version would appear in the log as `SampleName_V2.xml` (and this could continue increasing indefinitely, but the most I've seen is V8).

I need a way to `SELECT` every entry in this log, but only keep the entry with the `latest version number` on the filename.

I feel like there's got to be an easy answer to this, but I've been trying to think of it all day and can't come to it.

Anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: `We do have a DateTime field in every row as well`, if that helps.

Comment: `ORDER BY datetime filed DESC` gives the result na?

Comment: If you have a way of identifying the unique files, then you can use a CTE with partition, but we need more info on how to identify unique file?

Comment: @LJT have a look at my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that will do the job for you.  Idea is to use temp table that also holds file names without _v suffix.

I’ve probably made this more complex than needed but you’ll be able to see the point

```
DROP TABLE #TmpResults
CREATE TABLE #TmpResults
(
Original nvarchar(100),
WO_Version nvarchar(100),
Last_Update datetime
)

INSERT INTO #TmpResults
(Original, WO_Version, Last_Update)
VALUES 
('file1.xml', 'file1.xml', '01/01/2013'),
('file2.xml', 'file2.xml', '02/01/2013'),
('file2_v2.xml', 'file2.xml', '03/01/2013'),
('file3.xml', 'file3.xml', '01/01/2013'),
('file3_v2.xml', 'file3.xml', '01/02/2013'),
('file3_v3.xml', 'file3.xml', '01/03/2013'),
('file4.xml', 'file4.xml', '05/01/2013'),
('file5.xml', 'file5.xml', '06/01/2013'),
('file5_v2.xml', 'file5.xml', '06/02/2013'),
('file5_v3.xml', 'file5.xml', '06/03/2013'),
('file5_v4.xml', 'file5.xml', '06/04/2013')

SELECT 
P.WO_Version,
(SELECT MAX(Last_Update) FROM #TmpResults T WHERE T.WO_Version = 
P.WO_Version) as  Last_Update,
(SELECT TOP 1 Original 
    FROM #TmpResults T 
    WHERE T.Last_Update = 
   (      SELECT MAX(Last_Update) 
      FROM #TmpResults Tm 
      WHERE Tm.WO_Version = P.WO_Version) ) as Last_FileVersion
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT WO_Version
FROM #TmpResults
GROUP BY WO_Version
) P
```

Here is the SELECT query you can use to fill the temp table with SELECT INTO

```
SELECT 
Original_File_Name,
REPLACE(@Original_File_Name, 
SUBSTRING(@Original_File_Name, LEN(@Original_File_Name) - CHARINDEX('v_',REVERSE(@Original_File_Name), 1), LEN(@Original_File_Name) - CHARINDEX('v_',REVERSE(@Original_File_Name), 1)), 
SUBSTRING(@Original_File_Name, LEN(@Original_File_Name) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@Original_File_Name), 1) +1 , LEN(@Original_File_Name) - CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@Original_File_Name), 1))) as WO_Version,
Last_Update
FROM OriginalDataTable
```

Comment: I don't think you could have made it any simpler -- I struggled all night trying to do this within the table; I think the temp table was exactly the way to go. Brilliant solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will gives you the result

```
SELECT TOP(1) filename
FROM table
ORDER BY datetime_field DESC
```

If you are sure that your version number is in the order of `_V1 to _V8` this will help you

```
SELECT TOP(1) filename
FROM table
ORDER BY  CAST(RIGHT(SUBSTRING([Filename],1,LEN(SUBSTRING([Filename], 0, 
                        PATINDEX('%.%',[Filename])) + '.') - 1),1) AS INT)
```

**UPDATED**
I am suggesting another method which gives you all the file name with latest version.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(@products,LEN(@products)-CHARINDEX('_',@products))
                          ORDER BY date_field DESC
                          /*OR order by  CAST(RIGHT(SUBSTRING([Filename],1,LEN(SUBSTRING([Filename], 0, 
                            PATINDEX('%.%',[Filename])) + '.') - 1),1) AS INT) ASC*/
                          ) AS rno,
      filename
   FROM table
 )

 SELECT * FROM cte WHERE rno=1
```

Comment: This still includes every version of the file. I need a way to only SELECT the last version and remove the old versions from the results (so a V3 of a file will appear in the results but the V2 and original will not).

Comment: This log doesn't just have the versions for one file. It's a log of 40,000 files, most of which are unique and have no version number suffix, but some of which have a V2, V3, etc revision.

Comment: you are trying to select one among them or do you want the latest one of all?

Comment: I want the latest of every single one of these filenames included in the same list. And the first version of a file will not have a version number attached, only once a file get revised do we start adding the _V# suffix.

Comment: if you are using second one you need to start with V#. If order by date is ok then no need of that